# Silverlight - Perspective 3D

Tags: silverlight, 3d

I am considering using Silverlight for a project I am working on. This project will need to show a 3-Dimensional cube. Is this possible in Silverlight?

I see a lot of examples that a basically 2-sides of one item. Kind of like a sheet of paper. Is this what "perspective" 3D is? How is perspective 3D different than normal 3D?

Thank you!

Comment: There's no such thing as normal 3d, and if there was, it would probably be 3d with perspective projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at [Kit3D](http://www.codeplex.com/Kit3D) for Silverlight. Someone also created a [silverlight3d.com](http://silverlight3d.com/) site, but it current just has three reference articles and a link to Kit3D.

It is also possible to emulate 3D as demonstrated by this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500570.aspx).

Comment: That MSDN article is a little out of date since it was written for Silverlight 2 which was before the perspective projection was added. Everything that is described in that article will of course still work, but it is probably neither the easiest nor the best solution anymore.

Answer (score 1):

The feature that was added in Silverlight 3 is referred to as "perspective 3D" to avoid confusion that might arise with someone expecting it be some kind of full scale 3d rendering API (like DirectX or OpenGl etc.) or something like WPFs UIElement3D.

The "perspective 3D" feature in Silverlight allows you to take any regular 2D UIElement and rotate it in 3D dimensions; you can think of it like a more powerful RenderTransform. There are two ways of setting a "Projection" on a UIElement, with a [PlaneProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.planeprojection%28VS.95%29.aspx) (simple) or with a [Matrix3DProjection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrix3dprojection%28VS.95%29.aspx) (more complex).

You could certainly use this feature to create a 3D cube, where each face of the cube is a UIElement with a Projection applied to it. However you would not use this feature to create something that required complex 3d models such as a 3D game.